# How route parameter assigns the value to property in Blazor?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

Below block of code is Blazor documentation. But I am not able to figure out how and on what basis 'text' route parameter assigns value to the Text property.

```
@page "/RouteParameter"
@page "/RouteParameter/{text}"

<h1>Blazor is @Text!</h1>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Text = Text ?? "fantastic";
    }
}
```

Comment: The router parses the `text` parameter from the URL and sets the value of the component. For instance, if the URL is `/RouteParameter/MyText`, the `Text` property will be set to "MyText". Is that what you are asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

Blazor matches route param with properties by ignoring the word's case.

---

Blazor gets all parameters from the route and all properties from your class and assigns it ignoring the case.

So the lower case `text` goes into `Text`.

This would also work

```
@page "/RouteParameter"
@page "/RouteParameter/{Text}" // upper case Text

<h1>Blazor is @Text!</h1>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Text = Text ?? "fantastic";
    }
}
```

But because normally the url doesn't have upper case, and C# properties starts with upper case, they maybe this comparison ignoring case.

Answer (score 3):

#### There's more reading!

The Blazor documentation you were reading is not intended to explain ALL of routing.  It only goes so far as to explain how Blazor uses ASP.NET Core Routing.

> [More on ASP.NET Core Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing)

---

#### Tying in to ASP.NET Core Routing

In your Blazor Web App's Startup.cs file you'll see something like the following:

```cs
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
        endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
    });
```

`MapBlazorHub()` is how Blazor ties into the ASP.NET Core Routing.

---

#### Blazor routing is using the same Router as MVC and Razor pages.

Example:

MVC -> `[Route("customer/{id:int}")]`  (attribute on a controller)

Razor Pages -> `@page "/customer/{id:int}"` (page directive)

Blazor -> `@page "/customer/{id:int}"` (page directive)

---

#### Step by step

Example route: `@page "/customer/{id:int}"`

- The route is navigated to by the end user
- The URL is matched to an endpoint by the ASP.NET Core Router
- The URL is tokenized into route values
- The `"{id:int}"` are processed by Route Constraints, and accepted or rejected, and in this case, converted to a strongly typed `int`
- The route values is packaged and given to your code (controller, component, etc), and it provides the customer id of `1` as a parameter.

> Warning : this is high level and glossing over some key things, please continue reading [More on ASP.NET Core Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing)